# Fallo al intentar abrir un excel .xlsm al escribir sobre el desde Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

AL escribir el siguiente código:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("archivo.xlsm")

df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'BBDD', index = False)

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

e intentar abrir luego el excel en cuestion me sale el siguiente mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No consigo saber el por qué. Si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradecería.

Gracias!

Comment: ¿por qué la extensión xlsm? ¿Has probado con xlsx?

Comment: Por que mi idea es guardar esos datos en la pestaña 1. Luego en la pestaña 2 de ese mismo excel.xlsm  se ejecute una macro que tire de esos datos de la pestaña 1 donde he guardado el dataframe y así luego recoger los datos calculados por la macro de la pestaña 2 y tratarlos en Python. Igual es un poco lío pero esa era mi idea

Comment: Entiendo entonces que el archivo .xlsm ya existe previamente y tiene en la segunda pestaña las macros? No sé si pandas te permite escribir una hoja en un libro así... Puedes si no hacerlo un poco más manual. Escribes desde pandas a un archivo xlsx auxiliar, que abres desde excel para copiar la primera hoja y pegarla al xlsm de las macros, desde el cual ya generas la tercera hoja que, esa sí, creo que podrías leer con pandas.

Comment: Sí, el archivo ya existe con datos anteriores y los botones de la macro están en la segunda pestaña. Hemos pensado la misma solución, pero quería saber si era posible hacerlo de la manera más automática posible. De todas formas miraré en la respuesta que me han dejado debajo a ver si es posible ¡Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Pandas no te va a dejar escribir directamente un Excel con macros y cambiar la extensión no va a funcionar porque Excel lo detecta como no válido (lo que te está ocurriendo ahora mismo)

Cuando me he encontrado con estas situaciones la solución más sencilla es utilizar XlsxWriter para adjuntar el .bin con las macros que previamente debes haber exportado.

Échale un vistazo a la documentación de [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_macros.html)

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("archivo.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

workbook  = writer.book
workbook.filename = "archivo.xlsm"
workbook.add_vba_project("./vbaProject.bin")

writer.save()
```